# How is $\sum^n_{k=1}\sum^n_{l=1}P_{ik}P_{jl}\sqrt{\lambda_l\lambda_k}\mathsf{Cov}(Z'_kZ'_l)$ equal to $\sum^n_{k=1}P_{ik}P_{jk}\lambda_k$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I have a proof of the following proposition:

Let $\sum$ be non-negative definite. Then $\sum$ is a covariance matrix.

Proof:

Suppose we are given an n.n.d matrix $A$. Since $A$ is symmetric, we recall that we can write $P^TAP=D$, where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$,and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the corresponding eigenvalues. Equivalently, $A=PDP^T$. Now let $(Z'_1,Z'_2,...,Z'_n)$ be a collection of random varibles, each with mean $0$, and with covariance $I_N$, and define $$Z_i=\sum^m_{k=1}P_{ik}\sqrt{\lambda_k}Z'_k$$

Now, observe that

$$\mathsf{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(\sum^n_{k=1}P_{ik}\sqrt{\lambda_k}Z'_k, \sum_{l=1}^nP_{jl}\sqrt{\lambda_l}Z'_l\right)=\sum^n_{k=1}\sum^n_{l=1}P_{ik}P_{jl}\sqrt{\lambda_l\lambda_k}\mathsf{Cov}(Z'_kZ'_l)=\sum^n_{k=1}P_{ik}P_{jk}\lambda_k=(PDP^T)_{ij}=A_{ij}$$

Could somebody please explain how the following is true?:

$$\sum^n_{k=1}\sum^n_{l=1}P_{ik}P_{jl}\sqrt{\lambda_l\lambda_k}\mathsf{Cov}(Z'_kZ'_l)=\sum^n_{k=1}P_{ik}P_{jk}\lambda_k$$

I don't understand how the second term is derived from the first term. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well then the identity matrix is the covariance matrix of $(Z'_1,\dots,Z'_n)$ so that: $$\mathsf{Cov}(Z'_l,Z'_k)=\delta_{lk}$$
i.e. takes value $1$ if $l=k$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

So the summation you mention only gives non-zero terms for indices $k,l$ that satisfy $k=l$.